# os x El Capitan ExecJs/RuntimeError -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, macos

When Ii try to access a page in angularjs I got the error message

> ExecJS::RuntimeError at /users/sign_in   (in
> /app/assets/javascripts/angularjs/app_require.js)

And it show the error come from here:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'angularjs/app_require.js' %>
```

Everything is installed, I checked on a different forum but still don't work.

## update

```
brew node info: node: stable 5.3.0 (bottled), HEAD Platform built on the V8 JavaScript runtime to build network applications https://nodejs.org/ /usr/local/Cellar/node/5.3.0 (2,827 files, 29.4M)  Poured from bottle From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/node.rb
==> Dependencies Build: pkg-config ✔ Optional: openssl ✔
==> Options
--with-debug    Build with debugger hooks
--with-full-icu     Build with full-icu (all locales) instead of small-icu (English only)
--with-openssl  Build with openssl support
--without-completion    npm bash completion will not be installed
--without-npm   npm will not be installed
--HEAD  Install HEAD version
==> Caveats Please note by default only English locale support is provided. If you need full locale support you should:   `brew reinstall node --with-full-icu`

Bash completion has been installed to:   /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
```

Comment: How did you install node (via homebrew?) Do you mind sharing the output of `which node` and `brew info node` ? Also don't forget that in OS X El Capitan you don't have the openssl headers anymore. `brew install openssl
&& brew link openssl --force`

Comment: I add the brew node info in my post. And yes i installed it via homebrew. OpenSsl is installed too.